# Date Format in VisualForce Page

Tags: visualforce, formatting

I need this date format in a visualforce page as `MM/dd/yy`, below is the code. But in page it display as `Fri Mar 08 00:00:00 GMT 201903/08/19`, Can you please help me on this?

```
<apex:commandLink value="{!a.Date__c}" action="{!timesheetDetails}" >  
                                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yy}">
                                    <apex:param value="{!a.Date__c}" />                                         
                                </apex:outputText>
                                <apex:param value="{!a.Id}" name="getsk" assignTo="{!TimesheetDays}"/>
                            </apex:commandLink>
```

Comment: Try adding single quotes around the "/" characters in the format definition.

Comment: tried, no luck. 
    **<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yy}">
                                        <apex:param value="{!a.Date__c}" />                                         
                                    </apex:outputText>**

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `value` parameter in `apex:commandlink` so you're getting the date twice.  If you remove it, it should work.

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!timesheetDetails}" >  
    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yy}">
        <apex:param value="{!a.Date__c}" />                                         
    </apex:outputText>
    <apex:param value="{!a.Id}" name="getsk" assignTo="{!TimesheetDays}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```